# Underscore prefixed codes in URLs?

Tags: python, django

I am running Django 1.6.2 with Python 3.3.2

From what I see Django treats URL `/trains/direction/msk_5fkur/` as equal to `/trains/direction/msk_kur/`. In other words Django treats `_5f` the same way as `%5f`.

I could not find any info on this except mentions in [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18381).

Is this a Django feature? If so, why is it needed?

Comment: It seems like a open bug. And this is the commit that's causing this I think https://github.com/django/django/commit/90e530978d590a5bdcf75525aa03f844766018b8.

Comment: @Bibhas, FYU - I changed to bug url

Comment: The updated url to bug is for 1.4 not 1.6.

Comment: See the last comments. Also I linked the bug just to show that this behavior is known, but I cannot find any mention of it in other places. BTW link in your first comment doesn't work

Comment: Not sure why https://github.com/django/django/commit/90e530978d590a5bdcf75525aa03f844766018b8